# Add local administrator account on Windows 10 computer on .loc domain

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, administrator, active-directory, domain

Our company has a .loc domain with several Windows 10 computers on it. One of the computers, let's call it ComputerA, is used by an employee, let's call him Sam, who has non-administrator domain user account.

On ComputerA, we want to add a local administrator account that would not be on the domain but that Sam could to occasionally install software on ComputerA only. Is this possible?

We recognize that it's likely not a best practice, but are curious if it's possible.

Note that I will eventually pass my domain administrator responsibilities to another employee.

Every time Sam wants to install even a small productivity tool on ComputerA, it requires that Sam get a domain administrator to logon to ComputerA to install it.

Because of an overburdened and inefficient IT group at the company, it's such a headache for Sam to install a productivity tool that he doesn't do it, which in the long-run is decreasing his productivity.

Comment: Why not use a domain user account that's a member of the local `Administrators` group? Why does it have to be a local group? (A domain account is easier to manage)

Comment: Every version of Windows has a built-in Administrator account.  You could just use that, but I totally agree, create a domain user and make it part of the local Administrator user group

Comment: "Why does it have to be a local group"--I meant "local user".

Comment: What version of Windows is running. You don't mention if the machine is in fact joined to the domain although I would assume it is but please clarify this.

Comment: As stated in the title, the machine is running Windows 10 and yes it is on the domain ("Windows 10 computer on .loc domain")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered how to do this:

1. Open Computer Management as an administrator
2. Go to System Tools - Local Users and Groups - Users
3. Right click to Add New User
4. When the new user has been created, right click on that user and select Properties
5. Select Member Of tab
6. Click Add button
7. Click the Advanced button
8. Click the Find Now button
9. Choose the target local administrator group name
10. Click Ok

https://www.isumsoft.com/it/how-to-add-user-to-local-administrator-group-in-windows/